# MongoDB (Mongoose) data structure question

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, database-schema

I'm curious about the best way to represent this kind of situation in Mongo. I have my own idea, but I'm curious on what the general consensus/best practice actually would be.

Imagine I have two collections:-

```
Employees
 --> _id
 --> FirstName
 --> Surname
 --> Email

Comments
  --> _id
  --> PersonReference
  --> CommentDate
  --> Comment
```

Now imagine that Employees can come and go and the 'Employees' collection is always up-to-date. However, in the event that an employee has ever made a comment, the full information on the comment including who made it must be available.

The way I would propose to tackle this problem, is to organise the structure like this instead:-

```
Employees
 --> _id: _id
 --> FirstName: string
 --> Surname: string
 --> Email: string

Comments
  --> _id: _id
  --> CommentDate: date
  --> Comment: string
  [-] --> PersonReference
  [+] --> Employee: object { _id: id, FirstName: string, Surname: string, Email:string }
```

So essentially, I would have a list of 'Active Employees' and at a time where a comment is made, I would duplicate the employee information into the Comments collection document (rather than use a reference).

From a high level perspective, is this considered best practise?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating the employee info in the comments collection is really a bad idea.
When an employee info needs to be changed, it will also needs to be updated in the comments.

You have a few options:

1-) Embedding the comments inside the Employee schema:

In this method we have no separate Comments collection.

If you have no need to independently query comments, this method makes sense.
This way we can access a user and his/her comments in one db access and without needing any join (populate or lookup).

The schema for this can be like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  comments: [
    new mongoose.Schema({
      commentDate: Date,
      comment: String
    })
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);
```

2-) Parent referencing:

In this method we keep the reference of the comments in the Employee schema.
If you don't need to access to employee from a comment, this can an option.

Employee Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);
```

Comment Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  commentDate: Date,
  comment: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

3-) Child referencing

In this method we keep reference of the employee in the comments.
So if you need to access the comments from an employee we need to use [Populate Virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) feature of mongoose. Becase in employee schema we don't have a reference to the comments.

Employee Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: String,
    username: String,
    email: String
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true } // required to use populate virtual
  }
);

// Populate virtual
employeeSchema.virtual("comments", {
  ref: "Comment",
  foreignField: "employee",
  localField: "_id"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);
```

Comment Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  commentDate: Date,
  comment: String,
  employee: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Employee"
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

4-) Both parent and child referencing:

With this method, it is possible to select comments from employee, and employee from comments. But here we have some kind of data duplication, and also when a comment is deleted, it needs to be done in both of the collections.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);
```

Comment Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  commentDate: Date,
  comment: String,
  employee: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Employee"
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many database implement kind of `no-delete` collections, implementing a `delete/active` flag for each document.

For example, `Employees` collection would become :

```
Employees
 --> _id: _id
 --> FirstName: string
 --> Surname: string
 --> Email: string
 --> Active: boolean
```

This way, you keep track on employees data that has been deleted, and prevent documents duplication if you have database size restrictions.

PS: nowadays you can be tackled keeping user data if they ask deletion (RGPD)

---

EDIT: This solution with boolean may not work if `Employees` document is **updated** and you want to **keep employees firstname,name,mail,etc at the time he made the `Comment`**.