# mongoose save multi level nested objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to implement my first mongoose based REST API.

I tried now for days but cannot get this up and running. I would like to save the survey with an array of controls and for each control an array of controlProperties.

In different scenarios I got it to save survey with controls array but without controlProperties and sometime with not even controls array.

Can someone please help me understand my error?

Thanks a lot.

The structure is as follows:

Survey
    -- Array of control
        -- Array of controlProperty

My schema files are:

survey.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Control = require('./control');

const surveySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 4,
        max: 255
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        max: 1000
    },
   closeDate: {
       type: Date,
       required: false
   },
   controls: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Control' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Survey', surveySchema);
```

control.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Survey = require('./survey');

const controlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    survey: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Survey'},
    controlType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    isInput: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true

    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    controlProperties: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ControlProperty' }]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Control', controlSchema);
```

controlProperty.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Control = require('./control');

mongoose.Schema.Types.String.checkRequired(v => v != null);

const controlPropertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    control: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Control' },
    propertyName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    propertyValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('ControlProperty', controlPropertySchema);
```

My node.js code to receive the post data is this one:

/routes/survey.js

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {


        Survey.find({ _id: req.body._id })
            .exec()
            .then(result => {
                if (result.length >= 1) {
                    return res.status(409).json({
                        message: "Survey exists"
                    });
                } else {

                    const survey = new Survey({
                        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                        name: req.body.name,
                        description: req.body.description,
                        closeDate: req.body.closeDate,
                        order: req.body.order
                    });


                    let controlData = req.body.controls;
                    let arControls = [];

                    if(controlData != null) {

                        for (var i = 0, clen = controlData.length; i < clen; i++) {
                            let c = controlData[i];
                            let control = new Control({
                                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                                controlType: c.controlType,
                                name: c.name,
                                isInput: c.isInput,
                                order: c.order
                            })

                            let controlPropertyData = c.controlProperties;
                            let arControlProperty = [];

                            if(controlPropertyData != null) {

                                for (var j = 0, cplen = controlPropertyData.length; j < cplen; j++) {
                                    let cp = controlPropertyData[j];
                                    let controlProperty = new ControlProperty({
                                        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                                        propertyName: cp.propertyName,
                                        propertyValue: cp.propertyValue, 
                                        order: cp.order                                
                                    })

                                    arControlProperty.push(controlProperty);
                                }

                                ControlProperty.insertMany(arControlProperty, forceServerObjectId=true,function (err,data) {
                                    if(err!=null){
                                        return console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    console.log(" " + j + " controlProperties for control " + i +  " saved");

                                    control.controlProperties = data;
                                    console.log(data);
                                });


                            } 
                            arControls.push(control);


                        }

                        Control.insertMany(arControls, forceServerObjectId=true,function (err,data) {
                            if(err!=null){
                                return console.log(err);
                            }
                            survey.controls = data;

                            console.log("controls saved");
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    }

                    survey
                        .save()
                        .then(result => {
                            console.log("survey saved");
                            res.status(201).json(survey);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(500).json({
                                error: err
                            });
                        });
                }

        });
    });
```

sample post data:

```
{   
    "name": "TestSurvey",
    "description": "This is a test survey",
    "controls":  [
        {       
            "controlType": "Label",
            "name": "Label1",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 1,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontSize", 
                    "propertyValue": "Large",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "BackgroundColor", 
                    "propertyValue": "Darkgreen",
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontAttributes", 
                    "propertyValue": "Bold",
                    "order": 3
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalOptions", 
                    "propertyValue": "Fill",
                    "order": 4
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalTextAlignment", 
                    "propertyValue": "Center",
                    "order": 5
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "TextColor", 
                    "propertyValue": "White",
                    "order": 6
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "Text", 
                    "propertyValue": "Paris Work-Life Balance",
                    "order": 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {       
            "controlType": "Label",
            "name": "Label2",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 2,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontSize", 
                    "propertyValue": "Medium",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "Margin", 
                    "propertyValue": "20,0,20,0",
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontAttributes", 
                    "propertyValue": "Bold",
                    "order": 3
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalOptions", 
                    "propertyValue": "StartAndExpand",
                    "order": 4
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalTextAlignment", 
                    "propertyValue": "Center",
                    "order": 5
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "Text", 
                    "propertyValue": "Dear [[FirstName]], \nwas your workload on the case 12345 - 67(Company) compliant to the BCG Work Life Balance Ground Rules over the past week ?",
                    "order": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "controlType": "PWLBControl",
            "name": "PWLB1",
            "isInput": true,
            "order": 3,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                        "propertyName": "Margin", 
                        "propertyValue": "20,0,20,0",
                        "order": 1
                }
            ]
        },      
        {
            "controlType": "Button",
            "name": "button1",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 4,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "Text", 
                    "propertyValue": "Submit",
                    "order": 1
                },
                        {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalOptions", 
                    "propertyValue": "StartAndExpand",
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "IsSubmitButton",
                    "propertyValue": true,
                    "order": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "controlType": "Image",
            "name": "image1",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 5,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "Source",
                    "propertyValue": "",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "VerticalOptions",
                    "propertyValue": "End",
                    "order": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey there, I am new o MongoDB as well, but I will try to help you. Did you design this code? there is something that does not convince me. You declare Survey inside control and control inside survey, What are you trying to accomplish, it seems like a document inside a document inside a document, a circular loop: the document is the subdocument, but is the document as well.

Comment: another thing,  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, no need, mongoose creates for you the id, unless you really need to define your own id

Comment: I am an absolute beginner. I only set the arrays downward. The uplink is unused in my code. At the beginning I was not sure how to do that in MongoDB. So the survey field in control and the control in controlProperty is unused and unset.

Comment: Hey there, the answer you got from @SuleymanSah is what I would suggest! Now it should work! please, let us know if it worked!

Comment: Should you want to use populate, what you have used in your code, instead of the suggestion given by @SuleymanSah , there is a nice tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2oWH1g2Fng. Since you are a beginner, my suggestion is to stick to answer given here, it is simpler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to keep seperate collections for controlProperties and controls.
You can embed `controlPropertySchema` inside `controlSchema`, and embed `controlSchema` inside `surveySchema`.
So at the end we will have only one collection for survey.

This will make possible to create a survey in one insert operation. And also you will be able to get all survey info in one read operation.

Also there are a few suggestions:

1. It is better to not add _id fields to the schemas, mongodb will
   handle it.
2. I see you use it if a survey exists with the given _id. Better to
   use `name` field to check if a survey already exists.
3. `min` and `max` options are used for Number type, for String type
   `minlength` and `maxlength` are used. [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators)

So the `surveySchema` must look like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const controlPropertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  // control: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Control" },
  propertyName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  propertyValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  order: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});

const controlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  //  survey: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Survey'},
  controlType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  isInput: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  order: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  controlProperties: [controlPropertySchema]
  //controlProperties: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ControlProperty" }]
});

const surveySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    maxlength: 1000
  },
  closeDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  },
  controls: [controlSchema]
  // controls: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Control" }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Survey", surveySchema);
```

Now we can create a survey with this post route:
(Please note that we don't make any conversions, since our request body's structure is the same as surveySchema)

```js
router.post("/surveys", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let survey = await Survey.findOne({ name: req.body.name });

    if (survey) {
      return res.status(400).send("A survey already exists with that name");
    }

    const result = await Survey.create(req.body);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
      return res.status(400).send(err.errors);
    }
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

In your request body, there was an empty `propertyValue` so I changed it to `"propertyValue": "I was empty"`,
and also a boolean value instead of string, so I changed it to `"propertyValue": "I was true"`

You can use this corrected request body:

```
{
    "name": "TestSurvey",
    "description": "This is a test survey",
    "controls": [
        {
            "controlType": "Label",
            "name": "Label1",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 1,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontSize",
                    "propertyValue": "Large",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "BackgroundColor",
                    "propertyValue": "Darkgreen",
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontAttributes",
                    "propertyValue": "Bold",
                    "order": 3
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalOptions",
                    "propertyValue": "Fill",
                    "order": 4
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalTextAlignment",
                    "propertyValue": "Center",
                    "order": 5
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "TextColor",
                    "propertyValue": "White",
                    "order": 6
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "Text",
                    "propertyValue": "Paris Work-Life Balance",
                    "order": 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "controlType": "Label",
            "name": "Label2",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 2,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontSize",
                    "propertyValue": "Medium",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "Margin",
                    "propertyValue": "20,0,20,0",
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "FontAttributes",
                    "propertyValue": "Bold",
                    "order": 3
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalOptions",
                    "propertyValue": "StartAndExpand",
                    "order": 4
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalTextAlignment",
                    "propertyValue": "Center",
                    "order": 5
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "Text",
                    "propertyValue": "Dear [[FirstName]], \nwas your workload on the case 12345 - 67(Company) compliant to the BCG Work Life Balance Ground Rules over the past week ?",
                    "order": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "controlType": "PWLBControl",
            "name": "PWLB1",
            "isInput": true,
            "order": 3,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "Margin",
                    "propertyValue": "20,0,20,0",
                    "order": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "controlType": "Button",
            "name": "button1",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 4,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "Text",
                    "propertyValue": "Submit",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "HorizontalOptions",
                    "propertyValue": "StartAndExpand",
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "IsSubmitButton",
                    "propertyValue": "I was true",
                    "order": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "controlType": "Image",
            "name": "image1",
            "isInput": false,
            "order": 5,
            "controlProperties": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "Source",
                    "propertyValue": "I was empty",
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "propertyName": "VerticalOptions",
                    "propertyValue": "End",
                    "order": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey there  @SuleymanSah did you test this code?? I am not sure it is a good idea the nesting you did. I have tried that in the past, and nesting like yours is hard to manage. His solution seems okay, I have done some tests myself, not with his solutions, but with a similar approach. You seem to have sub sub documents, and I have no idea how to save one, do you? Best

Comment: Please, see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58591001/can-i-define-a-subdocument-inside-a-subdocument-in-mongo

Comment: @JorgePires yes I tried this code, it works as expected. In this scenario embedding is the best option. What do you ask about your question there?

Comment: Hey there, I was designing a set of forms, and I learnt how to work with one level of nesting, but more than one, I was unable to do. For example, suppose a have a form, then I have a field, and another field, which of them is a subdocument. How can I access it, save... I have found quite challenging to work with sub sub documents. Maybe you have a different experience!

Comment: @JorgePires for modeling options check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235301/mongodb-mongoose-data-structure-question/59235785#59235785) answer. For updating the subdocuments we generally use positional $ operator. Check the docs please: [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)  [2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

Comment: I have tested your code the way you posted here, it is not working; it gives back bad request. I will try again later. Based on my experience, it does not work saving subdocuments as you did, of course, I am new to MongoDB, and I may be missing something; I was curious to see if you solved my problem with subdocuments, I have tried several times, and no success, I wanted to save subdocuments as you did, it is elegant.

Comment: @HugoHiasl, any success?

Comment: @JorgePires I tested this, and know it is working,  if you want you can ask your problem as an question

Comment: can you send me the code, please? using any online code runner. I would appreciate!

Comment: @JorgePires all the code is in this answer. If you get a bad request, check your request body, it means your request is not correct.

Comment: I have already tried without request, direct in the code, and it still does not work. Do not worry, this is not priority to me, I have solved my abovementioned problem already by avoiding sub sub documents, just using sub documents, no more; I was just puzzled the way you solved and wanted to learn something new. Thanks for your attention and kindness!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the valuable input.

Finally I found the reason why my code did not work from the beginning. Only thing I needed to change was to do the assignment of controlProperties array to control and the controls array to survey not in the success function of the insertMany but after the whole inserMany command.

So I changed:

```
  ControlProperty.insertMany(arControlProperty, forceServerObjectId=true,function (err,data) {
      if(err!=null){
          return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(" " + j + " controlProperties for control " + i +  " saved");

      control.controlProperties = data;
      console.log(data);
  });
```

to:

```
  ControlProperty.insertMany(arControlProperty, forceServerObjectId=true,function (err,data) {
      if(err!=null){
          return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(" " + j + " controlProperties for control " + i +  " saved");

      console.log(data);
  });

  control.controlProperties = arControlProperty;
```

Thanks for you support.

Comment: Hey there, I am glad things worked out just fine after all! have learnt two new things here, thanks to you: populate and saving in multi-level.   @SuleymanSah, today I have created a simple code to test your assumption regarding the multi-level saving structure in mongo, and it works (I have tested an 4 level, and it works!), now I know a powerful tool! two to be precise.